# Wait till the response body changes in Cypress

Tags: javascript, api, get, xmlhttprequest, cypress

I am trying to automate a situation where I need to wait until in the response body I see the value **Success**. What I tried:

```
cy.server()
cy.route({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://endpoint.com/api/readsomething'
    auth: {
        'username': username 
        'password': password
    },
    response: {}
}).as('checkStatus');

cy.wait('@checkStatus').then((ele) => {
expect(ele).should('have.property', 'response.body.latest_run.status', 'Success')
})
})
```

I am getting an error as: `cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: checkStatus. No request ever occurred.`

Would be great if you can let me know where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to find the solution by looking into the request cypress doc - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html#Request-Polling

Since the API endpoint I wanted to call was different from the application I was working on so I used `cy.request()` instead of `cy.server() cy.route()`

```
    function getStatus() {
        cy.request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: Cypress.config('endpoint'),
            auth: {
                'username': Cypress.config('username'),
                'password': Cypress.config('password')
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            if (response.body.status == "Success")
                return
            else
                getStatus()
        })
    }

    //Trigger the above function
    cy.then(getStatus)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger an UI action. If the API requests are fired on page load, you will need to do `cy.reload()`, `cy.visit()` or click on a nav in order to make the requests happen. If it's something trigger by users' interactions. Like a button click, you will need to trigger that by `cy.click()` the button or something similar. And then wait for it.

Here is the real world example (simplified a bit) from our [project](https://github.com/oharastream/ohara/blob/master/ohara-manager/client/cypress/it/paper/elements.test.ts#L555-L577):

```js
cy.server();
cy.route({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'api/pipelines',
  response: mockedData,
}).as('getPipelines');

cy.reload(); // Reload the page and so we can wait for until `@getPipelines` request is resolve
cy.wait('@getPipelines');
```

Comment: Hi @konekoya Thanks for your answer. But unfortunately it didn't solve the problem as I was trying to GET a completely different api endpoint from the application I am working on. So instead I tried to look into `cy.request()`cypress doc and I found this https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html#Call-cy-request-over-and-over-again and I was able to achieve I was looking for.

Comment: Glad you have resolved the issue. You could actually answer your own question and accept it :)